# How can I adjust my plt.axhline position?

Tags: python

Why is my plt.axhline distorted?
I hope that the X-axis of this horizontal line starts at 0.2 and ends at 0.8. How to design it?
Attach my code as below, thank you

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.full((20,),3)
print(x)
y=2*x+1
print(y)
y1=y[0]
x1=x[0]
plt.axhline(y1,0.2, 0.8, color= 'r')
plt.axvline(x1, 0.2, 0.8, linestyle= '--')
plt.show()
```

[image: axhline error]

Comment: Your `x1 = 3` so if you set the X-axis to 0.2 - 0.8 range, you will miss the cross of the x and y lines. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify the coordinated of both lines (x=3, y=7) and that's why your plot is located at that coordinates. You can change the coordinate and add limits to xaxis (with `plt.xlim`). In axhline you specify coordinates first (in your case 7), then how far does it go regarding the plot (0.2 would be reaching left 20% mark of the whole plot, 0.8 -> to the right).

This should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.full((20,),3)
print(x)
y=2*x+1
print(y)
y1=y[0]
x1=x[0]
plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.axhline(y1,0.2, 0.8, color= 'r')
plt.axvline(0.5, ymin=0.2, ymax=0.8, linestyle= '--')

plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

Else you can do something like that:

You set `xlim` to `0,4` and then set the line to reach left 5% of the plot (0.05*4=0.2) and reach 20% of the plot to the right (0.2*4=0.08).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.full((20,),3)
print(x)
y=2*x+1
print(y)
y1=y[0]
x1=x[0]
plt.xlim(0, 4)
plt.axhline(y1,0.05, 0.2, color= 'r')
plt.axvline(x1, ymin=0.2, ymax=0.8, linestyle= '--')

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]